# Getopt::Long, Optional Arguments, and Greediness

Tags: perl, arguments, option-type, getopt

I'm trying to write a program that has an option that takes an
optional argument, in such a way that it accepts options in the same
fashion with the **exact** same behavior as `perl -i` or `git --color`.  Unfortunately
`Getopt::Long` doesn't *exactly* work that way and I can't get it to.  Allow me to explain.

Example #1: If you run `perl -i .bak`, it does not use `.bak` as a backup file
extension for editing in-place, as `perl -i.bak` would.

Example #2: If you run `git diff --color always`, it does not specify `always` for
the `--color` option; for that you must use `--color=always`.

I call that "**non-greedy**".

I cannot figure out how to configure `Getopt::Long` to handle this
scenario similarly.  Programs using it behave "**greedy**" in this regard.

Consider the following program:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

our $color;
our $backup;
Getopt::Long::Configure(qw(no_bundling));
Getopt::Long::GetOptions(
    "color:s" => \$color,
    "i:s" => \$backup,
) or die(":-(\n");

printf("\$color = '%s'\n", $color // '(undef)');
printf("\$backup = '%s'\n", $backup // '(undef)');
printf("\@ARGV = '%s'\n", join(', ', @ARGV));
```

and the following invocation, for example:

```bash
./foo.pl -i .bak --color always meow moo
```

Desired behavior:

```
$ ./foo.pl -i .bak --color always meow moo
$color = ''
$backup = ''
@ARGV = .bak, always, meow, moo
```

Actual behavior:

```
$ ./foo.pl -i .bak --color always meow moo
$color = 'always'
$backup = '.bak'
@ARGV = meow, moo
```

Comment: Looks like it isn't possible. The package even has an option `gnu_compat`, where it it stated at the end: `Note that --opt value is still accepted, even though GNU getopt_long() doesn't.` Time to email the author and perhaps then post the result here.

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, you can use the option terminator `--`.

```bash
./foo.pl -i .bak --color -- always meow moo
```

Answer (score 0):

> I cannot figure out how to configure Getopt::Long to handle this scenario similarly.

It seems it is not possible as noted by @Casper in the comments. But you can of course parse the command line manually. For example:

```
use v5.38;

our $color;
our $backup;

my @new_argv;
while (defined(my $arg = shift @ARGV)) {
    if ($arg eq '--color' && @ARGV && $ARGV[0] !~ /^-/) {
        # --color followed by a non-option argument
        $color = '';
        push @new_argv, shift @ARGV;
    } elsif ($arg =~ /^--color=(.*)/) {
        # --color=blue
        $color = $1;
    } elsif ($arg =~ /^--color$/) {
        # Just --color
        $color = '';
    } elsif ($arg eq '-i' && @ARGV && $ARGV[0] !~ /^-/) {
        # -i followed by a non-option argument
        $backup = '';
        push @new_argv, shift @ARGV;
    } elsif ($arg =~ /^-i=(.*)/) {
        # -i=bak
        $backup = $1;
    } elsif ($arg =~ /^-i$/) {
        # Just -i
        $backup = '';
    } else {
        push @new_argv, $arg;
    }
}

# @new_argv now contains the arguments that were not processed
printf("\$color = '%s'\n", $color // '(undef)');
printf("\$backup = '%s'\n", $backup // '(undef)');
printf("\@ARGV = '%s'\n", join(', ', @new_argv));
```